# Translating FTP transfer code from WinForm to Windows-CE

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-ce

I'm having problems translating some code for FTP transfer from WinForm to Windows-CE C#.

I have this code for transfer from a local computer to an FTP server. It's working excellent on WinForm, I must have this on Windows-CE and it doesn't work. The code:

```
string MyFile = @"d:\PC.sdf";

string url = "ftp://127.0.0.1/PC.sdf";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(url);

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
// request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user name", "password");
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;

// byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(MyFile);

using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    int count = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(MyFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        while ((count = file.Read(buffer, 0, 100)) > 0)
        {
             reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some information on what isn't working?  I don't have a copy of CE to try it on, and even if I did it likely wouldn't be equivalent.  It's hard to help you debug if we don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: It is very unlikely that your mobile device is running an FTP server, don't use 127.0.0.1.  In addition, CF only support HTTP transfers, not FTP.

Comment: i think that i need to use OpenNETCF ???? can i get any sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific, "it does not work" wont get you very far on SO. As a start, I think the FTPWebRequest is not supported on WinCE, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/64971b7f-14db-4708-985b-67e6524d0c5a/)